# :has is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using  **$(':has')** to filter out a tree..it's working fine but, it's taking too much time to find out exact match...here is my code

```
 function filterLeftNavTree(filterData){  
  jQuery("ul.treeview").find("li").hide();
  if(filterData.indexOf("|")!=-1){
   var Data = filterData.split("|");
   for(i=0;i<Data.length;i++){
    $(':has(#'+Data[i] +')').show();
   }  
  }else{  
   $(':has(#'+filterData+')').show();
  } }
```

when i am using  `$('div:has(#'+Data +')').show();`  to improve speed...
then it's not showing exact match...
am i doing something wrong...?
i also tried with **.find()**..but couldn't get the desired solution...

any suggestion so that i can improve the performance of this code. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you reference `Data` within the loop shouldn't you be retrieving a specific index? -  `$(':has(#' + Data[i] + ')').show();`

Comment: yes thats fine...i missed that while typing here but in actual code it's fine

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is not to use `:has`; there are several other, faster ways to accomplish the same thing.

When selecting elements from the DOM by either ID or CSS class, `$('#' + filterData)` or  `$('.' + filterData)`, respectively, will do just that without incurring the overhead of a more generalized selector such as `:has`.

To solve your specific problem, it's helpful to note that multiple selectors can be passed to `$()` by separating them with commas.

For example:

```
var selectors = [];
for(i=0;i<Data.length;i++){
    selectors.push('#'+Data);
}
var filtered = $(selectors.join(','));
```

Comment: Or, `var filtered = $("#" + Data.join(", #"));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1)Removed unecessary check on filterData before split
2)Converted the filterData string to a jQuery selector to avoid looping.
3)Added contains selector instead of has

```
function filterLeftNavTree(filterData){  
  jQuery("ul.treeview").find("li").hide();
   var Data = filterData.replace("|", "), :contains(");
    $(':contains('+ Data +')').show();
}
```

Comment: actually filterdata is string containing more than one string seperated by |, and all these values corresponds to a node in a tree..so i am trying to hide those nodes which is in filterData string.my code is working fine as i written in my question.but when i am using $('div:has(#'+ Data +')').show(); , then its not working